# Responsibility Back End for displaying errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, design-patterns, model-view-controller, api-design

At my company, the front-end and back-end apps are completely separated. We are wondering whether the FE or BE is responsible to display error messages to be shown to our users.

At the moment, the back-end is sending nice error messages readable by end users e.g.: "Canada is not a supported country. Could you try again later or contact our helpdask at: help@company.com". Do you think it's the right way to do so or the back end should only send some data about the error and the front end formats everything?

Comment: It is a good programming practice to handle error's at FE.

Comment: @RohanKawade I don't know where you got that information, but it is most certainly not good programming practice to handle error's at the front end. If you have an error occurring at the back end, it should be processed at the back end, and return an error status, type, and message to the front end, which of course should be setup to expect errors from the backend and appropriately display error information / page. If you are only bothering to handle errors at the front end, what happens when the system is expanded to have a public API, mobile app API, SOAP etc.

Comment: Sorry my bad i mean to say validation's. I mistook it as validation.

Comment: Validation should be done in both backend (to protect your app/db from getting wrong inputs) and frontend (for better user experience).